# Can you answer a question which is on hold?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

I just noticed that an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959314/2530848) is posted after the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959230/want-to-show-to-sentence-in-on-message) is put on hold. Am wondering how does that even work?

Obviously "Post Your Answer" will be disappeared as soon as question is put on hold, If you were in middle of typing the answer you'll get a message saying that "Question is closed, no more answers will be accepted". I have seen this before.

So, I guess this is a bug? or policies changed (I mean this is allowed when you're typing an answer already)?

Comment: So @Oded you mean this is by design? If so since when?

Comment: Since a very very very very long time.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed (from May 2011)

Comment: When you post from the mobile UI, the *Question is closed* banner doesn't appear and you are not prevented from posting your answer. The server does stop answers after the post has been on hold for a few hours, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a grace period on the server that allows this to happen.

If someone is in the middle of writing an answer, the question gets closed and they post their answer (and assuming that the notification that it was closed never arrived), we will accept the answer.

This is as a courtesy to someone who was busy writing an answer - instead of rejecting it outright, we will save it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but once the "This questions has now been closed" banner appears, the "Post Your Answer" is disabled (client side on the full view, not the mobile view), so the grace period only applies to cases where you do not get the close notification.

Comment: @psubsee2003 You can enable the button again with browser developer tools.

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I recall hearing that before, but I was more verifying what I understood....  so if I am working on an answer and the question gets closed while I am typing it, the server may accept my answer, but unless I re-enable the button, I can't send it.

Comment: So what exactly determines whether you will get the notification that it was closed? (And I highly doubt in the cases where I've seen the symptom the OP describes that they're worked around it using dev tools.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are never notified while on the mobile view, that I know.  I'm guessing since the notification is sent via the web sockets, if your browser does not get the message, then you won't get the notification.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I highly doubt [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66264/1186), for example, was authored on mobile. Possible, but highly unlikely. So I'm wondering if there are other known cases where the closure doesn't get relayed correctly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - a temporary network disruption could cause the notification to never arrive. Or an error in javascript could cause javascript execution to stop (and hence no notification/validation).

Comment: And I thought it was witchcraft.